# Select all rows with the same value in column 1 but different values in columns 2 and 3 using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which looks like this

[image]

Each [Order number] can have 1 or multiple [Line number] and each [Line number] can have status [SHIPPED] OR [UNSHIPPED].

I want to select all the [Order number] which contain [Line number] having both [SHIPPED] and [UNSHIPPED].

For example these [Order number] contain [Line number] with [SHIPPED] and [UNSHIPPED] at the same time so it should be selected

[image]

Here is my query but it doesn't return the correct result

```
SELECT [Order number], [Line number], [SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED] 
FROM [mytable]
WHERE [Order number] IN (SELECT [Order number]
                         FROM [mytable]
                         GROUP BY [Order number]
                         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY [Order number], [Line number]
```

Any suggestions please what is missing in my query ? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `/`, spaces, commas in the names of your table. This can lead to errors. Could you give your data as *text*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [Order number]
    FROM mytable
    WHERE [SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED] IN ('SHIPPED', 'UNSHIPPED')
    GROUP BY [Order number]
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED]) = 2
)

SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE [Order number] IN (SELECT [Order number] FROM cte);
```

The CTE finds all order numbers which have both shipped and unshipped records.  It works by first restricting a given order's records to only those having shipped/unshipped, then it asserts that the distinct count of that group is 2, implying both types of shipments are present.

Answer (score 1):

your query was almost right just need a little bit change i did that

```
    SELECT [Order number],[Line number],[SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED] FROM [mytable]
    WHERE [Order number] IN (
    SELECT [Order number]
    FROM [mytable]
    WHERE [SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED] IN ('SHIPPED', 'UNSHIPPED') --added where clause
    GROUP BY [Order number]
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED]) >= 2 --changed this condition
    )
    ORDER BY [Order number],[Line number]
```

Answer (score 1):

In opposite to other answer, I think, you mean that [Line number] has to have both statuses, i.e.:

```
OrderNumber LineNumber UNSHIPPED/SHIPPED
1           20         SHIPPED
1           20         UNSHIPPED
2           30         SHIPPEd
2           40         UNSHIPPED
```

then, required reuslt would be only [Order number] = 1, since it has line with both statuses.

Accordingly to this logic, here's query:

```
SELECT OrderNumber,
       LineNumber,
       [Unshipped/Shipped]
FROM (
    SELECT OrderNumber,
           LineNumber,
           [Unshipped/Shipped],
           COUNT(DISTINCT [Unshipped/Shipped]) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNumber, LineNumber) cnt
    FROM my_table
    WHERE [Unshipped/Shipped] IS NOT NULL
) a WHERE cnt > 1
```

Or with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT OrderNumber,
       LineNumber
FROM my_table
WHERE [Unshipped/Shipped] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY OrderNumber, LineNumber
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Unshipped/Shipped]) > 1
```

Comment: Hi, I think you cannot use distinct in count with partition by.

Comment: @PawanKumar I think you can :)

Comment: I am getting this "Msg 10759, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.
" with above query.

Answer (score 1):

another

```
with
    shipped as (select distinct [Order number] from mytable where [SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED] = 'SHIPPED'),
    unshipped as (select distinct [Order number] from mytable where [SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED] = 'UNSHIPPED'),
    both as (select [Order number] from shipped intersect select [Order number] from unshipped)

select * from mytable where [Order number] in (select [Order number] from both)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select all the [Order number] which contain [Line number] having both [SHIPPED] and [UNSHIPPED].

Your question is specifically asking only about orders, so the result set should have one row per order.  I would generally approach this using aggregation:

```
select [Order number]
from mytable
where [SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED] in ('SHIPPED', 'UNSHIPPED')
group by [Order number]
having min([SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED]) <> max([SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED]);
```

Another clever method uses `intersect`:

```
select [Order number]
from mytable
where [SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED] = 'SHIPPED'
intersect
select [Order number]
from mytable
where [SHIPPED/UNSHIPPED] = 'UNSHIPPED';
```

If you actually want the line numbers, use `JOIN`/`IN`/`EXISTS` with the above as a subquery.  Another method uses window functions.